# java.lang.IllegalStateException: container base add child?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

```
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\PRINCE SHARMA\Downloads\Compressed\apache-tomcat-8.0.33-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am getting these errors in my `tomcat apache` window in console afer running my application. The application runs fine in browser and nothing seems suspicious but I do not have any idea why these errors shows up in 'tomcat apache console'

My tomcat apache version is 8
and i'm using java se 8.

Comment: u need to upload ur code so that we can help.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code the problem is in tomcat server

Comment: Do you have any `<Context>` elements in `conf/server.xml`? Other that your own application, do you have any other applications deployed, or other directories in `webapps/`? Are there any other error messages in any other log files?